# Subscribing to distributed jobs in Python

Tags: python, jobs

I'm looking for a way of distributing jobs across multiple computers in a particular way.

When someone asks for a job to be done, it should be sent to the computer with the least load.  If someone else asks for the same job, it should subscribe to the result of the job that already exists instead of creating another job.  All consumers on a job should be effectively synchronous -- they just sleep until they get the result, and wake up immediately when it is ready.  If a job is already done when you request it, you should just get the result immediately.

How would you accomplish this in Python?

So far I have looked at task queues like rabbitmq and celery, but the prospect of subscribing to the task results seems messy and might require gratuitous amounts of queues.